# Is there any way I can loop this?

Tags: javascript, loops

How do i write a loop that console.log all numbers until it hits the "lotto" at 8, and when it does it, it also console.logs 8 but it stops there? Here is the code:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

function lottery() {
if (randomNumber === 8) {
    return randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!";
} else {
    return randomNumber + ": Sorry! No prize this time.";
}
};
```

I tried several time to make a for-loop but it didn't seem to run as I would like.

Comment: Where is the loop in this code?

Comment: @Balastrong No I haven't made a loop, because I didn't know what to put in it. As i explained at the top, how can I write this code that it console.logs through all the random numbers, until it hits lotto/8?

Comment: Then it's not how StackOverflow work. You should try to write your code first, then you can ask why it's not working if you don't succeed. Let's have a look at how a [for loop works](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). You won't learn too much if someone just gives you the code.

Comment: @emilmooe i believe you can use setInterval() method and inside that generate random number and checks for your condition and if your condition is reached use clearInterval() to stop the execution.

Comment: @Balastrong Yes I understand.. I'm just really struggling with loops in general, and I thought a for-loop was fitting in this code, but I just could not wrap my head around what I was supposed to have in the loop, or if i needed a loop at all. But thanks for the link though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you out ?

```
function lottery(winningNumber) {
  var won = false;
  while (!won) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (randomNumber == winningNumber) {
      console.log(randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!");
      won = true;
    } else {
      console.log(randomNumber + ": Sorry! No prize this time.");
    }
  }
}
lottery(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function again with a new number. The following recursively calls lottery, assigns a new numbers to randomNumber and tests it.

```
function lottery() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
if (randomNumber === 8) {
    console.log(randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!");
    return randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!";
} else {
    console.log(randomNumber + ": Sorry! No prize this time.");
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    lottery()
    return

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean you just want continously generate a new random number until it's equal to 8?

```js
let lottoFinished = false;

function lottery() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (randomNumber === 8) {
        lottoFinished = true;
        return randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!";
    } else {
        return randomNumber + ": Sorry! No prize this time.";
    }
}

while (!lottoFinished) {
    console.log(lottery());
}
```

I tried this code and it works.

Comment: function should not be defined inside loop.

Comment: i did some modifications for you.Here is the code.


`let lottoFinished = false;

function lottery(randomNumber) {
    if (randomNumber === 8) {
        lottoFinished = true;
        return randomNumber + ": Congratulations! You won!";
    } else {
        return randomNumber + ": Sorry! No prize this time.";
    }
}

while (!lottoFinished) {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(lottery(randomNumber));
}`